# Merge Number of Excel Files and load to SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, merge

I am trying to merge a number of files. About 40,000 excel files all in exactly the same format (columns etc).

I have tried to run a merge command through CMD which has merged them together to a point but the CSV file it has merged to I am unable to open due to the size of it.

What I am trying to find out is what is the best process to merge such a large amount of files and then the process to load them into SQL server.

Is there any tools or something that may need to be customised and built?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a tool for that, but my first idea is this, assumed you are experienced with Transact SQL:

- open a command shell, change to folder where your Excel files are stored in and enter the following command: `dir *.xlsx /b > source.txt`

This will create a textfile named "source.txt", which contains the names (and only the names) of all your Excel files

- import this file in a SQL Server table, i.e. called "sourcefiles"
- create a new stored procedure, which contains a cursor. The cursor should read your table "sourcefiles" in a loop row by row and store the name of the actually readed Excel file in a variable, i.e. called "@FileName"
- in this loop perform a sql statement like this for every readed Excel file:

  ```
  SELECT * INTO dbo.YourDatabaseTable
  FROM   OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=@FileName',
  'SELECT * FROM [YourWorkSheet$]')
  ```
- let the cursor read the next row

Replace "YourDataseTable" and "YourWorkSheet" with your needs.

`@FileName` must contain the full path to the Excel files.

Maybe you have to download the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0-Provider before executing the sql command.

Hope, this helps to think about your further steps

Michael

edit: have a look on [this](http://sqlandme.com/2013/04/15/sql-server-import-data-from-excel-using-t-sql/) website for possible errors